# Random number in time period

Tags: kotlin

How to solve a problem with Kotlin when I want to generate random numbers in time period (eg. 1 sec) and than than that numbers collect somehow and make Sum of that numbers.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you have with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routines of what you wanted are very simple. First, run a loop of how many random numbers that you want. Run a for loop that many times. Each time you generate a random number, add the value of that random number to a variable to keep track of the sum. Add that random number to a list. Then let the program go to sleep for a specific amount of time in milliseconds. The program below is a short example.

Note that, if the random number generated is a negative number, it will be flip back to its positive value. That will not work for integer.min value. However, this is just an example.

```
import java.util.Random
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    val howManyNumber = 5
    val delayTime = 1000L  // ms 
    val randomNumbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var sum = 0

    for (i in 1..howManyNumber){
        var randN = Random().nextInt()
        randN = if (randN > 0) randN else randN * -1
        sum += randN
        randomNumbers.add(randN)
        Thread.sleep(delayTime)
    }
    println(sum)
    println(randomNumbers)
}
```